# Proposals are not launched

Tags: discussion, area-51, site-proposal

[More than 10](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta) proposals are already crossed [90 days](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) but still now they are in *Public Beta* stage. Why these proposals are not [launched](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=launched) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Related blog post:  [When Will My Site Graduate?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/)

Related discussion:  [Is Home Improvement ever going to get out of public beta?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28/is-home-improvement-ever-going-to-get-out-of-public-beta)

90 days is the lower bound for a site to be in beta.  Beyond that, there are several factors that tie into the health of a site.

You can see stats for sites on Area 51, for example:  [Home Improvement stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/170/home-improvement).